# ggplot2 - reordering aes fill based on y-numeric, but calculated for each instance of factor x. Is this possible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've searched everywhere but cannot seem to find even a messy / hacked way of creating this plot.

I would like to plot a column chart with:

**x** = categorical factor, sorted in descending y order

**y** = numeric variable, summed

**fill** = categorical factor, sorted in descending y order - BUT having this calculated separately for **each occurrence** of x.

For example, the below code (using data from datasets) will nearly sort everything as I want, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to tell ggplot to reorder the fill for each x.

```r
library(tidyverse)

UCBAdmissions <- as.data.frame(UCBAdmissions)
UCBAdmissions$Dept <- as.factor(UCBAdmissions$Dept)
UCBAdmissions$Gender <- as.factor(UCBAdmissions$Gender)

plot <- UCBAdmissions %>% 
  ggplot(aes(
    x = fct_reorder(Dept, Freq, .fun = sum),
    y = Freq,
    fill = fct_reorder(Gender, Freq, .fun = sum)
  )) +
  geom_col() + coord_flip() + labs(fill = "gender")

plot
```

[image: plot from sample data, not quite correct]
I would like to keep Dept A showing Male closest to the axis, then Female,
but change Dept E to show Female closest (or any Dept where Female > Male).

Any ideas? Open to a messy solution at this point :)
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`position_stack` help here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_stack.html):

> position_fill() and position_stack() automatically stack values in
>   reverse order of the group aesthetic

So we can get what you want by adding mapping group to frequency. Since the data includes two Admit categories, I did some pre-processing here to combine them.

Now for each Dept, the stacking order is determined by which Gender has the higher number.

```
plot <- UCBAdmissions %>% 
  count(Dept, Gender, wt = Freq) %>%   # outputs n = total Freq per Dept/Gender
  ggplot(aes(
    x = fct_reorder(Dept, n, .fun = sum),
    y = n,
    group = n,
    fill = fct_reorder(Gender, n, .fun = sum)
  )) +
  geom_col() + coord_flip() + labs(fill = "gender")

plot
```

[image]